# unable to start plutus-playground-server after full rebuild --> /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, nix

After having to completely re-install an OS and setup a development environment. attempting to run the plutus-playground-server after building it wiht `nix-build -A plutus-playground.server` once in nix-shell I get the error:

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-server]$ plutus-playground-server
plutus-playground-server: for development use only
/nix/store/fm77y43lzpgnay4pyc48jwpln0lnmrk3-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 3: nix-build: command not found
/nix/store/fm77y43lzpgnay4pyc48jwpln0lnmrk3-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: nix-build: command not found
/nix/store/fm77y43lzpgnay4pyc48jwpln0lnmrk3-plutus-playground-server/bin/plutus-playground-server: line 10: /bin/plutus-playground-server: No such file or directory
```

What ive tired:
completely deleting /nix/store
deleting plutus-apps and clonging.
various tags:
ea0ca4e9f9821a9dbfc5255fa0f42b6f2b3887c4
week01:
41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a
week05:
62efdd2bfab3e076d40e07f8f4d7864a7f2ccc91

OS: Ubuntu 20.04,

nix (Nix) 2.6.1

Comment: what is to 'to source the nix profile.'

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out im loosing my mind. I had forgotten to source the nix profile.